# Hive alter serde properties not working

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I'm trying to change the existing Hive external table delimiter from comma `,` to `ctrl+A` character by using Hive ALTER TABLE statement

```
ALTER TABLE table_name SET SERDEPROPERTIES ('field.delim' = '\u0001');
```

After the DDL I could see changes

```
show create table table_name
```

But when I select from Hive, the values are all NULL (underlying files in HDFS are changed to have ctrl+A delimiter).

I have repaired the table also by using msck.

Only way to see the data is dropping and re-creating the external table, can anyone please help me to understand the reason.

**Table Syntax :**

> ```
> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table_name`(
>   col1,
>   col2,
>   col3)
> PARTITIONED BY ( 
>   `ing_year` int, 
>   `ing_month` int, 
>   `ing_day` int)
> ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
>   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
>   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
> STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
>   'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
> OUTPUTFORMAT 
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
> LOCATION
>   'hdfs://location/'
> ```

Comment: What do you mean by "But when I select from **HDFS** the values are all NULL" ? Don't you mean `Hive` or `Impala` ?

Comment: In HIVE , Alter table is changing the delimiter but not able to select values properly. it returns null.

Comment: It would also help to see the statement you used to create the table

Comment: table is created long back , now I am trying to change the delimiter from comma to ctrl+A.

Answer (score 7):

An `ALTER TABLE` command on a partitioned table changes the default settings for **future** partitions.

But **it will not apply to existing partitions**, unless that specific command supports the `CASCADE` option -- but [that's not the case](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AddSerDeProperties) for `SET SERDEPROPERTIES`; compare with [column management](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ChangeColumnName/Type/Position/Comment) for instance

So **you must ALTER each and every existing partition** with this kind of command

```
ALTER TABLE table_name PARTITION (ing_year=2016,ing_month=8,ing_day=31)
SET SERDEPROPERTIES ('field.delim' = '\u0001');
```

So now it's time for you to run a `SHOW PARTITIONS`, apply a couple of RegEx on the output to generate the list of commands, run these commands, and be happy ever after.

*Side note: I can tell you it was REALLY painful to rename a column before the `CASCADE` stuff was finally implemented...*

Comment: but I am getting the error , FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Unable to alter partition. alter is not possible

Comment: Damn, yet another Hive feature that does not work... Workaround: since it's an EXTERNAL table, you can safely DROP each partition then ADD it again with the same `location` -- and it will inherit the new default `SerDeProperties` from the parent table.

Comment: ...but as always, test this trick on a partition that contains only expendable data files. As you know, Hive DDL commands have a whole shitload of bugs, and unexpected data destruction may happen from time to time.

Comment: Thanks , I have already tested by dropping and re-creating that works , Problem is I have partition from 2015 onwards in PROD. Special care required to re-create that is the reason I was trying to change through alter but very clear it wont work :(

Comment: OK, so why don't you (1) rename the HDFS dir (2) DROP the partition that now points to thin air _[no possible data loss...]_ (3) ADD the partition on the new location?

Comment: Yes @Samson we do any of the approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can not ALTER SERDER properties for an external table.
What you could do is to remove link between your table and the external source.
Example if is an Hbase table, you can do:
1) ALTER TABLE MY_HIVE_TABLE SET TBLPROPERTIES('hbase.table.name'='MY_HBASE_NOT_EXISTING_TABLE')
MY_HBASE_NOT_EXISTING_TABLE must be a nott existing table.
2) DROP TABLE MY_HIVE_TABLE;
3) Recreate your hive table by specifing your new SERDE Properties
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE MY_HIVE_TABLE(
 MY_colums
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  '...' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
...)
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'hbase.table.name'='z_app_qos_hbase_temp:MY_HBASE_GOOD_TABLE');

Answer (score -1):

Put this command for change `SERDEPROPERTIES`.

```
alter table airlinetestcsv 
SET SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde';
```